# Detect contrast, comparison or example in an english sentence

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

Is there any tool or technique available in NLP / machine learning so that I can easily detect presence of contrast, comparison or example in an English sentence? For example, lets consider the following sentences:

> 1. Students often **cram** at the last minute; **however**, spaced study proves more effective.
> 2. Many **atolls** can be found in the Pacific Ocean; 
>      **similarly**, other **coral islands** are found in the Caribbean Sea.
> 3. **Unguents**, **such as** first aid cream, Cortaid, Vick-Salve, and Deep heat, are found in most homes.

Sentence 1 shows contrast to the word "cram" with "spaced study" with the use of the word "however".

Sentence 2 is showing comparison - "atolls" followed by "similarly", then "coral islands".

Sentence 3 is giving examples of "Unguents" followed by "such as" and the related example words.

I need to detect presence of such contrast, comparison and example in a sentence for the specified keyword. In our "case", "cram", "atolls" and unguents are the keywords.

Comment: [Discourse analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_analysis) is an active area of research. Are you looking for something foolproof, or do you just want something that can identify trigger words like "however," "similarly," and "such as?" Or perhaps you want to find the "such as" to say that it's an example, and then identify the subjects: "Unguents," "cram," and "atolls?" What is the desired output for your three examples?

Comment: I don't want foolproof one. And, I want the indication that, for example, for sentence 1, contrast is present by the use of "however". Further, more important one, I need to get two parts of the sentence: the first part as "Students often cram at the last minute" and second part as "spaced study proves more effective". Since only presence of "however" may not always indicate presence of contrast, and also position of "however" may not always be at the middle of the sentence as in sentence 1, I want to extract two parts of the sentences effectively for further processing.

Comment: @sangam have you found such tools?

Comment: @RoyLi not yet. In fact I wanted to develop a classifier to classify sentences based on the "context clue" type present in them. I tried Dan Bikel parser, Naive Bayes and SVM using Stanford Classifier. But to no avail. Either I hadn't sufficient training sentences or I need different approaches. I ended up manually collecting such sentences.